# Como remover margens ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Adicionei um `ProgressBar` simples a um `LinearLayout`, no entanto notei que ele gera um margem acima e outra abaixo, tal como esta na imagem:

> [image: ProgressBar]

Essas duas faixas brancas, tentei remover de todas maneiras, as únicas que "parecem eventualmente" funcionar são os progressbar customizados, mas realmente eu 
gostaria de apenas remover as margens sem precisar de algo totalmente customizado.

Como posso remover essas margens?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="foo.bar.guilherme.exemplo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        tools:context="foo.bar.guilherme.exemplo.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"
            android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>

    <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/siteView"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: mas cara, se voce remover a bar que vc quer vc já está usando um componente customizada, riririri

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho eu não quero remover a bar, apenas reduzir o tamanho para que fique semelhante ao chrome, quando me referi ao customizado falo daqueles com imagens e assets, no caso não quero uma customização completa, tenho certeza que é possivel resolver isso sem injetar um monte de coisas

Comment: Ele quer deixar apenas a parte que carrega, como se fosse uma linha, falando grosseiramente, um exemplo, imagine que você vai por duas barras uma em baixo da outra, essas margens iriam atrapalhar, creio que esse seja o pensamento dele, pois também gostaria disso.

Comment: Nenhuma resposta te agradou @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: @Florida tecnicamente ambas funcionam, porém é uma questão de testes para poder afirmar todos fatores, eu geralmente deixo aberto minhas perguntas por um tempo para dar a oportunidade de aparecerem melhores respostas que as minhas proprias ;)

Answer (score 5):

Por padrão, o `progressBar` possui um preenchimento acima e abaixo, que podem ser retirados de algumas formas, como:

**Margin:**

Você pode definir a margem para um valor negativo, assim removendo o espaçamento. Um exemplo seria isso:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
        android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>
```

Outra forma seria alterando o **Height**, mas especificamente, o `android:minHeight` e o `android:maxHeight`, desta forma:

```
<ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:maxHeight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>
```

Lembrando que os valores **20dp** devem ser alterados para o seu layout.

Mais detalhes você pode ver [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14171471/4843158)

> A alteração da Margin ou do height pode depender da tela, ou seja, pode não funcionar com os mesmos valores para todos os tipos de telas.

Outra possível solução seria alterar a cor do seu `progressBar`. [Este artigo](http://android--code.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/android-progressbar-color.html) explica melhor como fazer algo parecido.

Caso seja para Android 4.0+, existe o [MaterialProgressBar](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar) que além de um layout inspirado no Material Design, permite mais algumas alterações.

Se não achou que nenhuma opção atenda o seu propósito, você sempre pode fazer [o seu próprio customProgressBar](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=custom+progressbar+android&oq=custom+progre&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2666j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), que geralmente é a opção de muitas pessoas.

Comment: Seria dip ou dp?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Creio [que seja indiferente](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/4843158). Mas em alguns sistemas a Google [utiliza dip](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread-release/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#297).

Comment: O primeiro exemplo não funciona bem, pois "o efeito" varia de lugar para lugar, layout para layout e resolução para resolução, vou testar o segundo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, como eu disse pode não funcionar. O ideal é dr uma lida com calma em [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) para entender um pouco. Existem outras opções de layout, como "forçar" o layout pai sobrescrever essa propriedade.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com mesmo propósito de inserir com margem negativa, porém com mais algumas pesquisas percebi que isso realmente não  funciona em todos os dispositivos. No Galaxy S6 por exemplo, mesmo com uma margem superior -6dp, ainda aparece espaço em branco acima da barra de progresso. Essa coisa de cada empresa modificar o SO Android dá nisso. =/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Li a documentação e é [dp mesmo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:maxHeightv), dentre as outras unidades padrões. Fiz a correção ma resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `dip` é o mesmo que `dp`, pode-se usar qualquer um. No entanto recomendo usar `dp` já que o `dip` não é mais referido na documentação.

Comment: @ramaral Eu pensei que seria algo assim, mas como não achei nenhuma referência na documentação (não olhei os releases anteriores), preferi não dar certeza. Obrigado por me esclarecer. xD

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que entendi após fazer testes o `ProgressBar` é um a parte de "fora" (aonde ficam as margens) a barra azul seria como um sub-item, ele não conta na altura definida do `layout_height`, então fiz um teste, fixei a altura de `14dp` e removi `-7dp` das margens de cima de de baixo, assim:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>
```

E funcionou perfeitamente:

[image: progressbar]

Note que setar uma altura bem maior assim:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>
```

Ficará algo como:

[image: progressbar]

Veja que a barra azul não muda de tamanho, então se fizer isto:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:id="@+id/siteProgress"/>
```

O resultado é o mesmo que o primeiro exemplo:

[image: progressbar]

Na lógica eu poderia setar o `android:layout_height` como 0dp ou 1dp, mas isso afeta os "sub-elementos", mas se eu usar margens negativas ele não afeta.

> Vou fazer mais uns testes e ver bem a documentação para detalhar, mas de inicio esta parece ser a solução que funciona para todos casos (ao menos os que eu consegui testar)